# On a class of groups

Tags: group-theory

What is known, or what can we say, about a group $G$ which has the following property:

*Every group homomorphism $\phi\colon G\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ maps $G$ into $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$?*

Obviously every group $G$ with trivial outer automorphism group has this property. However, there are also such groups with non-trivial outer automorphism group. Does every perfect group have this property?

Do such groups have a *name*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure such a specific property deserves a name.

An example of a perfect group without this property is $\mathrm{Alt}_n^n$ for $n\ge 5$ (let it act on itself by permuting factors).